# Front-end development tool for a community project

Tags: open-source, web-apps, gui, framework

I am working on a project for a literature club where people discuss books.

We have decided to create a web application for it.

Database will contain information about thousands of books members have read.
Information will include author(s), title, annotation, genre and many other attributes.

Members of the club shall be able to add and edit entries to the database.
They also shall be able to view the list of books in tabular form, search by a number of criteria,
vote for books (up and down), leave their comments, etc.

I have created a database schema and now working on web services to support it.
I am quite experience software engineer (Java, C++, SQL) in server-side development, but absolute novice in the modern front-end technologies. I did develop some front-ends, using JSP/HTML long time ago (over 15 years), but already forgot these skills.

Now I need recommendation, for open-source framework to help me develop such web UI in a short time. I can do it only couple hours a day after work when family choirs permit.
Your recommendation will be very appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a case for [Bookwyrm](https://bookwyrm.social/), which seems to do exactly what you want? [It's FOSS](https://github.com/bookwyrm-social/bookwyrm) and you can self-host it if you wish. Or join an existing instance otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Jelu](https://github.com/bayang/jelu).

- It is a "Self hosted read and to-read list book tracker".
- In a way, it is a self-hosted "Goodreads".
- You could probably use as is or amend to suit your purposes, since it is opensource.